# How to set exit status in spring batch application

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am writing a batch application in which I would like to set the exit status immediately when ever my application logic identify an issue and return.

For example I am setting the below status in my writer's write method.

```
stepExecution.getJobExecution().setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
```

eventhough the above statment is executed, am getting below message in logs and the exit code is seems to be success.

"Batch Execution Successful!"

May I know how can I set the exit code properly?

There are some ways to set after step.

Like:

```
    @AfterStep
public ExitStatus afterStep(){
    //Test condition
    return new ExistStatus("CUSTOM EXIT STATUS");
}
```

But I don't want to persist the exit stauts and set the exit status in the above method.

Answer (score 3):

You should properly intercept [job execution](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#interceptingJobExecution)-

```
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution){

    if( jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED ){

        jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("CUSTOM SUCCESS STATUS"));

    } else if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED){

       jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("CUSTOM FAILURE STATUS"));

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the difference between setting the ExitStatus in afterJob method and in the writer itself? I am bit confused here.

Comment: @Kodaganti The one you posted is meant to use a listener and overriding the afterStep call. My version just uses the reference and sets its exit status as you can't alter batch status.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and just solved it 5 minutes ago.
I have multiple steps doing 'stuff' and a default "failure step" that is called when all other steps throw an exception.

The steps that throw an exception will be Abandoned in 'spring-batch' logic, but I need them to be Failed so that I can restart them.
So, after trying with listeners and forcing statuses, I finally got it to work by updating the abandoned step(s) after the 'failure step' is called.

So my 'failure-step' will look like this :

```
public class EnleveDossiersRejetesEtMAJSteps implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    /**some business logic code for my step, AND the code bellow*/

    if (chunkContext.getStepContext() != null && chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution() != null) {
        Long jobExecutionId = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecutionId();

        batchTablesService.updateJobStepStatuses(jobExecutionId, BatchStatus.ABANDONED, BatchStatus.FAILED);
    }

    /** end the step like expected */
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

My 'batchTablesService' is a Service class that I created, which links to a DAO that simply retrieves all steps, then for all 'Abandoned' steps, it updates them to 'Failed'.
Like so :

```
@Override
public void updateJobStepStatuses(Long jobExecutionId, BatchStatus sInitial, BatchStatus sFinal) {
    log.debug("-- call updateJobStepStatuses(" + jobExecutionId + "," + sInitial + "," + sFinal + ")");

    List<BatchStepExecution> steps = getStepExecutions((int) (long) jobExecutionId, null);
    for (BatchStepExecution step : steps) {
        if (!step.getStatus().isEmpty() && step.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(sInitial.toString())) {
            step.setStatus(sFinal.toString());
            entityManager.merge(step);
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No custom interfaces or classes are required. Take a look at this -

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14075