# Spring batch flow - step java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to string batch and created flow for my solution.

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listner)
                .start(step2()).on("FAILED").to(step3())
                .from(step2()).on("COMPLETED")
                .to(step4())
                .next(step5()).on("FAILED").to(step6()).from(step5()).on("COMPLETED")
                .to(step7()).end().build();
```

My Question is how do spring check status "FAILED" and "COMPLETED".
If I need to provide user defined string then what method I need to override or implement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-Batch: how do I return a custom Job exit STATUS from a StepListener to decide next step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411731/spring-batch-how-do-i-return-a-custom-job-exit-status-from-a-steplistener-to-de)

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063815/how-to-set-exit-status-in-spring-batch-application)